# How to change and save my service&port setting in xampp

Tags: xampp

how can I change and save my  port in configure servicesettings. I could change my port number but can't save the portnumber.

```
Error:cannot create file "c:\Xampp\xampp-control-in".Acess is denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the read and write permission for xampp-control-ini file. if you dont, then try to contact your system admin